# libgdx 1.5.5, help font loading-.ttf

Tags: java, fonts, libgdx

Hi I'm making a asteroids clone using java and libGDX and have had some trouble trying to load in a ttf font and simply displaying it and i have no idea what I'm doing wrong I've looked at many sites but they all have outdated information (I'm using the latest version of freetype).

Here is code:

```
SpriteBatch sb;
BitmapFont font;

sb = new SpriteBatch();
font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/Hyperspace_Bold.ttf"), true);

sb.setColor(1,1,1,1);
sb.begin();
    font.draw(sb, Long.toString(player.getScore()), 40, 390);
sb.end();
```

I've created a folder in my assets folder called fonts fyi.
P.S. players score is just 0

EDIT: the sb.setColor and everything preceding is in its own render method but i just put it here for simplicity purposes. The purpose of this post is that I'm not sure HOW to use a ttf font type and display it in the latest version of libGDX.

Comment: Is you position correct? Try creating bitmap font with empty constructor for debuging purpose.

Comment: Are you sure your code is in the correct methods. The last four lines of your code appearing in your question should be in the render method. The initialization of sb and font should be in your show/create method.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, this is not how you use `.ttf` files. `BitmapFont` doesn't support `.ttf`. You have to use `FreeTypeFontGenerator` to create a `BitmapFont` using a `.ttf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured it out. Finally! I needed to use a freeTypeFontGenerator like this:

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/Hyperspace_Bold.ttf"));
    FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.size = 12;
    BitmapFont font = generator.generateFont(parameter);
```

generator.dispose();

then just this in the draw/render method!:

```
sb.begin();
    font.draw(sb, Long.toString(player.getScore()), 40, 390);
sb.end();
```